# Uncrustify with VS Code is overindenting SOQL Lines

Tags: apex, vs-code, pretty

I use VS Code and use Uncrustify to format the apex code As per this [article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212382/format-apex-code-visual-studio-code/276669#276669).

This was working fine for me until all of a sudden my SOQL lines are now automatically indented after the WHERE clause.

What is currently happening:

```
List<Account> liAccounts = [SELECT Id
                            FROM Account
                            WHERE ..... 
                               (8tabs)     OR ....
                                      (8tabs)      OR ....
                                             (8tabs)       OR ....];
```

Desired Behaviour:

```
List<Account> liAccounts = [SELECT Id
                            FROM Account
                            WHERE ..... 
                            OR ....
                            OR ....];
```

I have tried changing some settings in the config however I cannot seem to get this fixed. It is proving to be very frustrating and time consuming.

Has anyone experienced this same behaviour?

Do you know how I can fix this so I can achieve my desired behaviour?

Comment: I solved this temporarily by disabling the 'format onSave' and switching to use the VScode extension 'Aura Helper' to format the apex class with. I am still unsure as to whether or this could have been fixed by using uncrustify. I hope Salesforce releases a formatter for Apex in VSCode soon.

Comment: Did you get the solution with uncrustify?

Comment: Nope, eagerly awaiting a 'Salesforce Apex Formatter', hopefully Salesforce (or someone) develops this extension in the near future.

Comment: Have you evaluated Prettier as an alternate solution? It's a little closer to a supported solution.

Comment: @DavidReed - I have now!... indeed it does work better. thanks. Any idea how I can added custom rules, like changing `list<account>` to `List<Account>` or `ID contactID` to `Id contactId` etc?

Comment: I don't know; I have only fairly superficial exposure to Prettier so far.

Comment: @DavidReed - I don't really need to get Uncrustify to work now... please may I get my 50 points refunded? :-)

Comment: @Robs I am fairly sure I can't do that!

Comment: @DavidReed - Fantastic! thank you!

Comment: anyone has any idea if this issue with uncrustify is fixed now?

Comment: Any luck in 2022 for this issue?

Comment: What's the setting to make this work in prettier ?